# What this mean in C ((TYPE){}). That fragment is taken from : __typeof__ ( ((TYPE){}).MEMBER )

Tags: c, macros, glibc, typeof

```
#define _IO_MEMBER_TYPE (type, member)       \
__typeof__ ( ((TYPE){}).MEMBER )
```

I have read this line in the header file "libiop.h" in the glibc and I got a bit confused about the curly brackets {} after (TYPE). What does `( (TYPE){} )` mean?

Answer (score 2):

> What does `( (TYPE){} )` mean?

It is not standard C, but it almost has the form of a C99 [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) of type `TYPE` (enclosed in parentheses), which would be appropriate to the apparent purpose.  It is non-standard because The brace-enclosed part of a compound literal must take the same form as an initializer for the designated type, and C does not permit empty initializers.  This variation would be fully standard whenever `TYPE` designates a structure, union, or array type:

```
((TYPE){0})
```

`__typeof__` also is non-standard, but it has the form of an identifier reserved for the implementation's use, so it is undoubtedly an implementation-specific extension, as one would presume accepting an empty initializer list is also.

Comment: AWESOME, thank you for your answer.  when he put the compound literal in side a parentheses like this ( (TYPE) {} ) and follow it with .MEMBER, then ( (TYPE) {} ) is actually an object which he would to access it to get MEMBER . like object.MEMBER. am I right ?

Comment: Yes, @Masalkhi, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The macro denotes the type of a specific struct member. The comment tries to explain this:

```
/* Type of MEMBER in struct type TYPE.  */
#define _IO_MEMBER_TYPE(TYPE, MEMBER) __typeof__ (((TYPE){}).MEMBER)
```

The macro is only used here:

```
/* Essentially ((TYPE *) THIS)->MEMBER, but avoiding the aliasing
   violation in case THIS has a different pointer type.  */
#define _IO_CAST_FIELD_ACCESS(THIS, TYPE, MEMBER) \
  (*(_IO_MEMBER_TYPE (TYPE, MEMBER) *)(((char *) (THIS)) \
  + offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER)))
```

This construct uses various GCC extensions to implement C++-style class inheritance. The direct way of writing this no longer works (or triggers warnings) with recent GCC versions. (The `libio` code and the C++ ABI it implements date back to GCC 2.95 in the 90s.)

This code is quite bad and you really should not use it as a model for anything.